# Modeling layered tree in rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to model a structure for a UI library where there exists a ViewNode which owns a RenderNode which owns a LayoutNode. These structures should at the same time form three distinct trees. A ViewTree, a RenderTree, and a Layout tree.

Is there any way of modeling this ownership without resorting to use of Rc? I don't want to use Rc<> because the ownership is clear from my point of view, The trees should never own their children (except for ViewNode), the wrapper is the owner. Each layer should also be able to be pulled out into a library and I don't want to force users of the library to use Rc<>.

Below is what I would *want* to do but what doesn't work. Should I go about this in a different way perhaps?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct LayoutNode<'a> {
    // .. Some fields
    children: Vec<&'a LayoutNode<'a>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct RenderNode<'a> {
    // .. Some fields
    layout_node: LayoutNode<'a>,
    children: Vec<&'a RenderNode<'a>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ViewNode<'a> {
    // .. Some fields
    render_node: RenderNode<'a>,
    children: Vec<ViewNode<'a>>,
}

fn make_tree<'a>() -> ViewNode<'a> {
    let layout_child = LayoutNode { children: vec![] };
    let layout = LayoutNode { children: vec![&layout_child] };

    let render_child = RenderNode { layout_node: layout_child, children: vec![] };
    let render = RenderNode { layout_node: layout, children: vec![&render_child] };

    let view_child = ViewNode { render_node: render_child, children: vec![] };
    let view = ViewNode { render_node: render, children: vec![view_child] };

    view
}


fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", make_tree())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a memory arena that uses indices instead of reference counted pointers.

Using [indextree](https://crates.io/crates/indextree) as an example:

```
pub struct NodeId {
    index: usize,
}

pub struct Node<T> {
    parent: Option<NodeId>,
    previous_sibling: Option<NodeId>,
    next_sibling: Option<NodeId>,
    first_child: Option<NodeId>,
    last_child: Option<NodeId>,
    removed: bool,

    /// The actual data which will be stored within the tree
    pub data: T,
}

pub struct Arena<T> {
    nodes: Vec<Node<T>>,
}
```

The `NodeId` struct is a simple integer index.

The nodes contain references to close by nodes (`parent`, `previous_sibling`, etc..) so to make for easy traversal.

A downside of this method is that it's very similar to manual memory management, in that you need to ensure that nodes are added/removed correctly to avoid dangling references. `indextree` has a lot of [error checking](https://github.com/saschagrunert/indextree/blob/a28ad6aa731c152206ba185cc159c73de11ac633/src/lib.rs#L410) when adding/removing nodes in the tree for this reason.

You might also want to have a look at [petgraph](https://crates.io/crates/petgraph):  While this is a `Graph` instead of a `Tree` you can use it as a tree.